# Formula Syntax/Logic help

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to compare text in two columns to auto calculate a result in a third calculated column (represented by an image).

The logic is as follows.

> If column1 value is Green and Column2 is Yellow - then I want to display a down arrow image.
>
> If column1 is Yellow and Column2 is Green - then I want to display an up-arrow image.

.... and so on, with various examples.

Just to experiment, I tried to write the formula for the first example, but keep getting syntax errors. Any chance I can get help to debug and figure out how to include multiple options in the same formula?

Here's what I came up with (which produces syntax error).

```
=IF( ( [Prior Status]="Green"
       , AND( [Current Status]="Yellow"
              ,"<img src='https:---URL HERE---down.png'></img>")`
```

Am I even close? I am not a programmer, and don't really understand the nuances of syntax, but like a monkey I can learn and copy :-) - with some guidance.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF( AND( [Prior Status]="Green"
          ,[Current Status]="Yellow"
        )
     ,"Value if true"
     ,"Value if false"
   )

=IF( AND(
          [Prior Status]="Green",
          [Current Status]="Yellow"
         )
     ,"Value if true"
     ,IF(
          AND(
              [Prior Status]="Yellow",
              [Current Status]="Red"
             )
          ,"Value if second condition is true"
          ,"Value if second condition is false"
         )
    )
```

So you would continue to use an "IF" statement for the "value if false" until you've added all of your statements.

Comment: I was able to make this work for one example, but seem to run into problems when I try and add another example (prob. just subtle syntax issues again). So if I wanted to repeat the above example several times over with  slightly different outcomse (in the same calculated column) e.g. 

=IF( AND( [Prior Status]="Grey"
          ,[Current Status]="Yellow"

Comment: You have to "nest" the if statements. I'll add a second example.

Comment: Have you run into issues with more than 7 IF statements. 
There are 12 possibilities (up to 7 by default, but can then I can then add a concatonate option )))))))&IF   to do many more - in theory.

Here's where I got the idea you can extend the number of IF statements past 7.
https://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/04/12/maximum-number-of-if-statements-in-a-calculated-column/

Comment: I would break it into multiple calculated fields, then the final calculated field would hold your result.